# Chainlink Hackathon 21 HardHat tutorial execute function in Smart Contract

Tags: task, solidity, execute, chainlink, hardhat

I would put this on stack overflow but it's specific to the hackathon. This is for the HardHat tutorial. I am trying to execute my get-number function on my smart contract.  My contract is deployed.  This is my command: npx hardhat get-number --contract 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3. This is the error I get: Error: call revert exception (method="getNumber()", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.5.0). Any thoughts would help...Thanks.

Here is the Task

```js
task("get-number", "Reads the number")
  .addParam("contract", "The contract's address")
  .setAction(async (taskArgs) => {
    const contractAddr = taskArgs.contract;
    const MyFirstContract = await ethers.getContractFactory('MyFirstContract');

    const accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
    const signer = accounts[0];
    const myFirstContract = await new ethers.Contract(contractAddr, MyFirstContract.interface, signer);

    let result = BigInt(await myFirstContract.getNumber()).toString();

    console.log('Stored number is: ' + result);
  });

module.exports = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error when following along with this hackathon tutorial.

My fix was to specify the `--network` when executing my task, get-number. So, in your example:

```
npx hardhat get-number --network localhost --contract 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3
```

This will execute the task using the Hardhat network the demo instructed you to start when you ran `npx hardhat node`

[Hardhat Network doc](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/)

[See Running Stand-Alone doc](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/#running-stand-alone-in-order-to-support-wallets-and-other-software)

I asked on the hackathon Discord why the demo didn't pass this, yet still worked, but haven't yet received an answer.

Comment: I tried but got an error :( . This is the error I got Error HH108: Cannot connect to the network localhost.
Please make sure your node is running, and check your internet connection and networks config. And my node was running. Did you do anything special to your network config?

Comment: I tried the kovan network and the code runs perfectly. IDK.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and the way I fixed it is to start hardhat with `npx hardhat node --hostname 0.0.0.0` instead of `npx hardhat node`

You'll need to deploy the contract to localhost as well: `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost`

Then using `npx hardhat --network localhost` to call the 2 functions.

Comment: thanks I'll try it out. It would be good to have a local hardhat environment. I just launched on kovan network and it works fine. Thanks for the follow up.